# The size of Galois group

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

In continuation to my last [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143414/is-the-size-of-the-galois-group-always-n-factorial):

In class we saw an example that says: $n=[\mathbb{F}_{p^n}:\mathbb{F}_{p}]=|\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{F}_{p^n}/\mathbb{F}_{p})|$ ; ($p$ is prime).

My thoughts are that if I look at any Galois extension then it is the splitting field of separable polynomials in the field I started with. I know that any automorphism of the extension field that fixes the field I started with sends each root of an irreducible factor (of one of the polynimials that the Galois expenstion is their splitting field), and also that for every such permutation I have an automorphism .

But since if an irreducable factor have $k$ roots then I can permute on them in $k!$ options I deduced that the size of Galois group is of the form $k_1!k_2!\cdots k_t!$, in particular it is either $1$ or devisable by $2$.

But this contradicts what I wrote in my first paragraph if for example we take $p=2,n=5$ since $5$ is odd.

Can someone please point out the mistake ?

Comment: Again, you have mistakenly assumed that all permutations are possible. This is not true, even if your polynomial is irreducible.

Comment: @ZhenLin - but if the extension is Galois I should have all roots, don't I ?

Comment: So? That doesn't mean all permutations are possible. You've already found an example of this happening. What more is there to say?

Comment: @ZhenLin - I don't understand...which roots I don't have (of which polynomial ?). I have all the roots of $x^{p^n}-x$...

Comment: You're not missing any roots. You're missing permutations!

Comment: @ZhenLin - can you explain please ? If I have all the roots, and they are all diferent then I should be able to fix the field I started with and send each root to *any* other root of his minimal polynomial. maybe I don't have all the roots of that minimal polynomial ? (but in this case it's still roots that are missing and not permutations...)

Comment: No, you can't. As I said, just because you have all the roots doesn't mean all permutations are possible.

Comment: @Belgi, as an example of what Zhen Lin is saying consider the following. If $\zeta=e^{2\pi i/5}$, then all the roots of $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ are $\zeta,\zeta^2,\zeta^3,\zeta^4$. But if an automorphism $\sigma$ of $\mathbf{Q}(\zeta)$ sends $\zeta$ to $\zeta^j$, for some $j=1,2,3,4$, then we must have
$$
\sigma(\zeta^2)=\sigma(\zeta)^2=\zeta^{2j},
$$ and similarly the image of $\zeta$ uniquely determines the images of $\zeta^3$ and $\zeta^4$. IOW, $\sigma$ cannot just permute those roots any which way we want. It has to respect the "hidden relations" among the roots.

Comment: @Belgi: You are right in that you *can* send any root to any other root. This merely means the Galois group has size $\geq k$.

Comment: @Belgi: In the last couple of days you have asked a number of questions related to field extensions or Galois groups which are all treated in books. What are you *reading* as you are learning this material? These questions would often be addressed in course textbooks, as the questions are quite basic (e.g., why a Galois group of a polynomial of degree $n$ does not have size $n!$). That doesn't mean the questions are unimportant, but they ought to be better understood by reading about worked examples in books.

Comment: @KCd - I attend the lectures in class and read the classical Aabstract algebra book by dummit and foote. Although I had a counter example later on (what I wrote in this post) I just didn't undersand what went wrong in my arguments - that there is a relation between the roots...I learned it in this post (not to say that the book doesn't have such an example...but I probably didn't notice the importance or something because I still was confused after reading the chapter). This subject have many points that are easy to miss...

Comment: @Belgi I have already given you an example to explain why the Galois group does not necessarily have to have order $n!$. Did that help with your understanding?

Comment: @Belgi: Galois theory is subtle when learning it. The  Dummit & Foote text has an extensive section on Galois theory (largely because Dummit was one of the authors) so you should read all the worked examples there carefully and see why each of them works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you don't seem to be convinced by your own example, let's look at another polynomial whose splitting field does not have the full symmetric group as its Galois group.

We take $\mathbb{Q}$ as our base field. Let $P(x) = x^3 - 3 x + 1$. For various reasons, $P$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $K$ be its splitting field over $\mathbb{Q}$, with three zeros $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$. Then, 
$$(x - \alpha)(x - \beta)(x - \gamma) = x^3 - 3 x + 1$$
so we can deduce various equations like $\alpha + \beta + \gamma = -1$. This can be done generically for any polynomial. But $P$ has a special property which gives an *extra* equation: 
$$(\alpha - \beta)(\beta - \gamma)(\gamma - \alpha) = 9$$
This is a polynomial equation with integer coefficients that the zeros of $P$ satisfy, so any automorphism of $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ must preserve this equation. But that means we cannot transpose just two of the roots, because that would invalidate the equation. So $\textrm{Gal}(K \mid \mathbb{Q})$ is the cyclic group of order 3.

---

Now, what *is* true is for any two zeros $\alpha$ and $\beta$ of a irreducible polynomial $P$, there is an automorphism $\sigma$ such that $\sigma (\alpha) = \beta$. But $\sigma$ could do anything else to any other zero – including $\alpha$. In slightly more sophisticated terms, the Galois group of the splitting field of $P$ is always a *transitive* subgroup of the symmetric group and acts *transitively* on the set of zeros of $P$. But it is not guaranteed to act *freely*.