# Galois Group of $p(x)=x^{5}+x^{4}+1$

Tags: galois-theory

For fun, I’m trying to find the Galois group of the polynomial $p(x)=x^{5}+x^{4}+1$.
I solved for the roots and got the splitting field $\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[3]{\frac{9+\sqrt{69}}{8}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{9-\sqrt{69}}{8}}, i\sqrt{3}\right)$. I now need to find the automorphism group of this, but I don’t know where to start.
I know an automorphism maps some nth root to its conjugate, but I don’t know what to do with such a complicated field extension.

Comment: You need more thant that to get the splitting field. Undoubtedly you found the factorization $$x^5+x^4+1=(x^2+x+1)(x^3-x+1).$$ So you need the three roots of the cubic factor $x^3-x+1$ and also the zeros of $x^2+x+1$ to get the splitting field. Seems to me that the splitting field is a degree twelve extension.

Comment: Ok so the splitting field is $\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[3]{\frac{9+\sqrt{69}}{8}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{9-\sqrt{69}}{8}}, \frac{-1+ i \sqrt{3}}{2}\right)$?

Comment: What are the other roots of the cubic factor? Are they in there already?

Comment: The Galois group of $(x^2+x+1)(x^3-x+1)$ is $C_2\times S_3$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen That's all I could find. There might be some information that I'm missing since I'm only in 11th grade. What are the other roots that I'm missing, and how would I get them?

Comment: @reuns Is that a general fact? The Galois group of a product of polynomials is the product of their Galois groups?>

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I wouldn't expect it to be the case at all. That was a guess off of Reuns' comment which phrased it as an obvious thing, seeing how the first product has group $C_2$ and the second (presumably) has the group $S_3$

Comment: @FShrike Sorry about jumping the gun. Here the quadratic factor has a quadratic splitting field $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$, and the discriminant of the cubic tells us that the only quadratic subfield of the splitting field of the cubic factor is $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-23})$. Therefore the two splitting fields intersect trivially. And two trivially intersecting Galois extensions are linearly disjoint, implying that the Galois group of the compositum is the direct product of the two Galois groups.

Comment: Ok, so then how do we find the automorphism group of this?

Comment: What do you know about the automorphisms of a field? Or of the possible automorphism groups of the splitting field of an irreducible cubic?

Comment: I don't know much about automorphism groups of irreducible cubics.
I know that the conjugate of $\sqrt[3]{a}$ is $\sqrt[3]{a^{2}}$. So I'm guessing it has something to do with the powers of the radicand?

Answer (score 6):

I guess it behooves me to promote the comments to an answer.

---

The quintic factors as
$$
f(x)=x^5+x^4+1=(x^3-x+1)(x^2+x+1).
$$
That particular quadratic factor is a friend we meet often. See for example [this old answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2012356/11619) for a description of a general class of trinomials having it as a factor. The cubic factor is gotten by polynomial division. Both factors are seen to be irreducible in $\Bbb{Q}[x]$ because we can quickly exclude the possibility of rational zeros (use [the rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem)). As the factors have degrees $\le3$, this implies their irreducibility.

Let $\omega=e^{2\pi i/3}=(-1+i\sqrt3)/2$ be a primitive complex root of unity of order three. The zeros of the quadratic factor are then $z_4=\omega$ and $z_5=\overline{\omega}=\omega^2$.

We then use Cardano's method for finding the complex zeros of the cubic factor. Following the procedure outlined e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/158152/11619), if $u^3$ and $v^3$ are the roots of
$$
y^2+y+\frac1{27}=0\qquad(*)
$$
such that $uv=1/3$, then $u+v$ is a zero of $x^3-x+1$. By the quadratic formula the roots of $(*)$ are $(-9\pm\sqrt{69})/18$. If $\alpha=\root3\of{(-9+\sqrt{69})/18}$ and $\beta=\root3\of{(-9-\sqrt{69})/18}$ are the real cube roots (both negative), then we have $\alpha\beta=1/3$, and Cardano's formula gives
$$
\begin{aligned}
z_1&=\alpha+\beta,\\
z_2&=\omega\alpha+\omega^2\beta,\\
z_3&=\omega^2\alpha+\omega\beta
\end{aligned}
$$
as the roots of the cubic factor $x^3-x+1$.

The splitting field of $f$ is thus $L=\Bbb{Q}(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4,z_5)$. Because $z_5=z_4^2$ we can dispose of $z_5$ as a generator. Because $z_1+z_2+z_3=0$ (Vieta) we can also dispose of $z_3$. Hence $L=\Bbb{Q}(z_1,z_2,z_4)$. Because the factor $x^2+x+1$ brought the primitive third roots of unity into $L$, we see that
$\alpha=(z_1-\omega z_2)/(1-\omega^2)\in L$. Therefore $L=\Bbb{Q}(\alpha,\omega)$.
[The primitive element theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem) further states that we can actually get $L$ by adjoining a single element to $\Bbb{Q}$. However, that is not very helpful for the purposes of identifying the Galois group $G=Gal(L/\Bbb{Q})$. I prefer to describe it as a group of permutations of the set of roots $X=\{z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4,z_5\}$.

If $\sigma\in G$ is some automorphism of $L$, then it must permute the elements of $X$ and once its action of $X$ is known, it will be completely determined. Obviously $\sigma$ must permute $z_4$ and $z_5$ amongst themselves (2 alternatives) and $z_1,z_2,z_3$ amongst themselves (6 alternatives). That gives a total of $2\cdot6=12$ possibilities. It turns out that all those $12$ permutations come from actual automorphisms in $G$, but that is not yet totally clear. To that end we calculate [the discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant), $D$, of the cubic. By plugging in the numbers we get $D=-23$. We observe that $D$ is not the square of a rational number. This has the following consequences (known from basic Galois theory):

- The splitting field $K$ of the cubic factor $x^3-x+1$ is a degree six extension of $\Bbb{Q}$. Furthermore, the Galois group $Gal(K/\Bbb{Q})$ is isomorphic to $S_3$. In other words, it permutes the zeros $z_1,z_2,z_3$ in all the possible ways.
- The only quadratic subfield of $K$ is $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-23})$.
- Because this subfield does not coincide with the splitting field $F=\Bbb{Q}(\omega)$ of the quadratic factor, we see that $K\cap F=\Bbb{Q}$.
- As both $K/\Bbb{Q}$ and $F/\Bbb{Q}$ are Galois, the previous bullet implies that they are linearly disjoint. It follows that their compositum $L=KF$ satisfies
  $$[L:\Bbb{Q}]=[K:\Bbb{Q}]\cdot[F:\Bbb{Q}],$$ and
  $$G\simeq Gal(K/\Bbb{Q})\times Gal(F/\Bbb{Q})=S_3\times C_2$$
  with the projections from $G$ to the two factor groups coming from restricting the automorphisms of $L$ to $K$ and $F$ respectively.

There are otherwise of seeing that $[L:\Bbb{Q}]=12$, and that already implies that $|G|=12$, and hence all the described $12$ permutations of $X$ must represent automorphisms.

---

If we look at $G$ by how it acts on the pair of generators $\alpha$ and $\omega$ we get a slightly different view. The zeros of
$$g(x)=x^6+x^3+\frac1{27}$$
are $\omega^i\alpha$ and $\omega^i\beta$, $i=0,1,2$. Let $M=\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$. As
$$12=[L:\Bbb{Q}]=[L:M]\cdot[M:\Bbb{Q}]=[M(\omega):M]\cdot[M:\Bbb{Q}],$$
it follows that $[M:\Bbb{Q}]$ must be equal to six (clearly $[M(\omega):M]=2$). Therefore $g(x)$ must be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$. Hence $\alpha$ has the listed six roots of $g(x)$ as its conjugates. We can conclude that $L$ is also the splitting field of $g(x)$.

Comment: As a group of permutations of $X$, the group $G$ is exactly like the Galois group that appeared [in this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/143783/11619). I converted the action to the subscripts of the roots, and made the numbering I used here to match with that.

Comment: I was first reluctant to make an answer exactly due to the similarity with the answer in the previous comment. I am very much against replicating old answers to this extent. I did realize that the chain of comments (made with a view of trying to make the OP to see the light) probably pre-empted other potential answerers. This is unfortunate, so I decided to bite the bullet.