# Why isn't $\mathrm{Gal}(E/K)$ always isomporphic to $S(\Sigma)$?

Tags: galois-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the size of the Galois group always $n$ factorial?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143414/is-the-size-of-the-galois-group-always-n-factorial)

Let $E/K$ be a Galois extension, where $E$ is the splitting field of a separable polynomial $p(x)\in K[x]$.

If $\Sigma=\left\{\;\mbox{roots of }p(x)\mbox{ in }E\;\right\}$, I know that the group $\mbox{Gal}(E/K)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S(\Sigma)$, the symmetric group of permutations of $\Sigma$. However, I don't know why it isn't isomorphic to the whole symmetric group: $S(\Sigma) \cong \mbox{Gal}(E/K)$.

My question is: why don't all the permutations of $\Sigma$ occur in $\mbox{Gal}(E/K)$?

Comment: I'm not big on algebra, so this might be false ^^. Consider the splitting field for a cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_n$ over $\Bbb Q$. Its roots are roots of unity, those that generate the group on $n$-th roots of unity. If you know the image of one of those roots, you will know the image of all the others because they are all powers of eachother, thus an automorphism is completely determined by one of its $\varphi(n)$ possible images.

Comment: Well, Oliver hit the nail on the head: he's given an example of a Galois Extension's Galois Group which is cyclic and, of course, $\,S_n\,$ isn't cyclic for $\,n>2\,$ ...